# Disable selection cursor for TextEditor in macOS-SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, selection, text-editor

[image]

I can disable selection and editing of the TextEditor with the code below:

```swift
TextEditor(text: self.$content)
    .allowsHitTesting(false)
    .disabled(true)
```

but this doesn't affect my cursor when hovering inside it, which is what I want. Is there a way to keep the main cursor inside a TextEditor when it is disabled, instead of the selection cursor?

I want this because other views I have in a ZStack above the TextEditor have this selection cursor at all times, which is annoying.

Comment: That does seem irritating. The normal methods of pushing an `NSCursor` don't seem to work at all. Since the `TextEditor` is disabled anyway, why not just use `Text` to display your content?

Comment: @jnpdx I probably should have mentioned it, but the goal of this is a plain text editor. So I need the text editing part and the ability to temporarily disable it so a menu or some other view above it isn't affected by the cursor thing, like a normal `Text` view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `overlay` modifier like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var string: String = "Hello, World!"
    @State private var disableStringSelection: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 5.0) {
            
            Color.white
                .overlay(disableStringSelection ? Text(string).font(Font.body).padding(.leading, 5.0) : nil, alignment: .topLeading)
                .overlay(disableStringSelection ? nil : TextEditor(text: $string).font(Font.body))
                .cornerRadius(10.0)

            Button(disableStringSelection ? "Enable Selection" : "Disable Selection") { disableStringSelection.toggle() }
            
        }
        .padding(5.0)

    }
    
}
```

[image]

### Update:

The new update will support dark mode as well:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var string: String = "Hello, World!"
    @State private var disableStringSelection: Bool = Bool()

    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 5.0) {

            Color(NSColor.textBackgroundColor)
                .overlay(disableStringSelection ? Text(string).font(Font.body).padding(.leading, 5.0) : nil, alignment: .topLeading)
                .overlay(disableStringSelection ? nil : TextEditor(text: $string).font(Font.body))
                .animation(nil)
                .cornerRadius(10.0)
                .foregroundColor(Color(NSColor.labelColor))
                .frame(width: 400.0, height: 200.0, alignment: .center)

            Button(disableStringSelection ? "Enable Selection" : "Disable Selection") { disableStringSelection.toggle() }
                .foregroundColor(Color(NSColor.labelColor))
            
        }
        .padding(5.0)

    }
    
}

extension NSTextView {
    
    open override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet { backgroundColor = NSColor.clear }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, that was the easiest way, that I could help. otherwise me and you should work on custom API.